# List box fully enclosed in div element

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web page that I prefer to keep as one page using ajax. The page has two columns with the right column being the active section. Using PHP and Jquery, I make a MySQL call to my database and display a table in the right column. This table has a section that displays stored list names. What I would like to do is then clear the div that has the table, and show a list box dynamically using a new query from list name in the table. I would prefer not to have to view it in a new page. The problem is everything I've read for the past three days just shows existing HTML with the list already in place and then the data is filled dynamically. Is it possible to show ALL of a list box code dynamically? My table can easily take up most of the page so this is not desirable. If not, is it then possible to have a model Listbox popup? Use a second page that has the Listbox and show that in my first form? Nothing I have read gives me real insight into what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: show us the code...

Comment: by using jquery you can clear your DIV very easy, so it is not a issue, to show a list box dynamically, you should call a AJAX function after you cleared your div, this ajax function will visit your PHP server, and this PHP function will visit your mySQL database, then generate an HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that

To clear a div,

```
function whatYouWant(){
    $( ".rightColumn" ).empty();
}
```

To achieve "and show a list box dynamically using a new query from list name in the table"

You can do it by AJAX in your whatYouWant(), the AJAX will call your PHP server function (or API), this API will ask your mySQL database, consturct the html string and return this built HTML string for javascript to display, like this dummy example

your page with javascript, certainly you can modify the AJAX to pass your criteria for the list to generate

```
function whatYouWant(){
    $( "#rightColumnDiv" ).empty();
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php/GetMyList",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
      $( "#leftColumnDiv" ).html( data );
    });   
}
```

in the test.php

```
<?php
function GetMyList() {
    //go to your mySQL database and fetch what you like to fetch dynamically
    //construct your list, output it    
    echo "<ul><li>Hello</li><li>GoodBye</li></ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry not to reply sooner. Was ill and unable to work. Thank you all for your responses.